# Python: dividing array based on other array

Tags: python

I have two arrays, for example:

```
a = [a, b, c, d, e, f, g]
b = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```

My first array is then splitted in a dictionary, in the following form:

```
dict = {key1: [a, c, e], key2: [f, g], key3: [b, d]}
```

I would like to get another dictionary, having the same partition but with the elements of array b:

```
dict = {key1: [1, 3, 5], key2: [6, 7], key3: [2, 4]}
```

In other words, I would like a correspondence between arrays a and b

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The brute force way to do this is to use [`index()`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) to look up the index of each element in the sublists of the dict and use that index to lookup the value in `b`.

You can do that in a single dict comprehension with something like:

```
a = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g']
b = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]

d = {'key1': ['a', 'c', 'e'], 'key2': ['f', 'g'], 'key3': ['b', 'd']}

{k: [b[a.index(l)] for l in v] for k, v in d.items()}
# {'key1': [1, 3, 5], 'key2': [6, 7], 'key3': [2, 4]}
```

You could make things a little more efficient by creating a lookup dict that maps letters to the indices of `a` so you don't need to iterate `a` the index each time with

```
a_lookup = {l: i for i, l in enumerate(a)}
# then: 
{k: [b[a_lookup[l]] for l in v] for k, v in d.items()}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `index` and list comprehension:

```
a = [a, b, c, d, e, f, g]
b = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
dict1 = {key1: [a, c, e], key2: [f, g], key3: [b, d]}
dict2 = {}
for key in dict1:
    dict2[key] = [b[a.index(i)] for i in dict1[key]]
```

How this works:

1. loop through `dict1`
2. Create  a dictionary key of that same name in `dict2`
3. For each value in that array, set the corresponding values of `b` as of that in `a`